# Unable to send outbound emails both internal and external on new installation of Exchange 2016

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, email-server, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

I have installed a WINDOWS 2016 server and Exchange 2016 without EdgeTransport. This is only windows server in our environment so I created  a new forest and new local domain.I have gone through Exchange 2016 post installation steps mentioned by Microsoft. Mail Flow is configured as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/plan-and-deploy/post-installation-tasks/configure-mail-flow-and-client-access?view=exchserver-2016.

I am able to receive email from outside but I am not able to send email internally or externally.

I have created 2 local accounts and sent emails from/to each other (using accpeted domain user@mycompany.com) and none of the emails is delivered. No email has bounced back.

I am under the impression that there is some problem in the DNS configuration somewhere and I would appreciate if some one can point in right direction.

Here are the environment details:

Windows 2016 Server HostName: EMAILSRVR
Windows 2016 has only one NIC configured with static IP address 10.10.10.10. NIC configuration DNS is 127.0.0.1.
Windows server private IP is NATTED to public IP of MX record via our firewall and appropriate ports are open.

Active Directory Domain - mycompany.local
Public Domain - mycompany.com

Public DNS:Public DNS settings are correct as I am able to receive email from outside.
 MX Record for mycompany.com is email.mycompany.com
 A Record for email.mycompany.com is 2.2.2.2 (Public IP Address)

On windows 2016 server,under the DNS manager:
    There is a zone "mycompany.local" under the Forward Lookup Zones. This zone shows  A record for EMAILSRVR having ip 10.10.10.10.
    I created another zone mycompany.com and created a CNAME alias "email" and pointed to EMAILSRVR ex explained by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Itw0ziIfw8U.

**EXchange Configuration:**
Exchange Admin Center -->Servers-->EMAILSRVR-->DNSLookups-->External DNS Lookups --> Custom Settings (8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4)
Exchange Admin Center -->Servers-->EMAILSRVR-->DNSLookups-->Internal DNS Lookups --> Name of the local NIC (which is configued with DNS as 127.0.0.1)

- Mail Flow - Added an accepted domain 'mycompany.com'  Mail Flow -
  Edited email address policies address name  to @mycompany.com  Mail
  Flow - Added the Internet Send Connector for the MX record  Servers -
  Updated Servers Outlook Anywhere to owa.mycompany.com  Servers
  -Configured the virtual directory external URL to email.mycompany.com Servers - Verified all the virtual directory external and internal
  URL are the same email.mycompany.com/*  Firewall - Open appropriates
  ports to the Exchange Server.  DNS - Added an A record to the
  Exchange Server public IP  DNS - Added a MX record with name
  email.mycompany.com  DNS - Added a CN record with name owa to value
  company.com  Cert - Imported an SSL certificate *.mycompany.com in
  Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

What detail information will be returned when you run get-messagetrackinglog in powershell? And check if these messages are stuck in queue when you run get-queue.

In addition, try to restart these 2 service, Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Transport Delivery and Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Transport Submission.

For further troubleshooting, you could test outbound emails via [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/exchange) and it will return some error messages for your reference.

Comment: I guess, after restarting the services most of the things got ironed out. I am able to send/receive emails locally as well outside. I am able to pass all the tests by EXRCA, I had to add autodiscover domain to the SSL certificate.

Comment: Yes, minimum host names that would be required in SSL are mail.domain.com and Autodiscover.domain.com.
For more details:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/certificates?view=exchserver-2019#best-practices-for-exchange-certificates